# Angular service, $http.get() with a route param?

Tags: angularjs

Typically when asking the API endpoint for JSON, I'd write something like this:

```
factory('User', function($http) {
    return {
        get: function() {
            return $http.get('/api/users');
        }
    }
});
```

However, how can I add a route parameter to get a specific user (RESTful show method)?

i.e. `/api/users/1` to get user number one.  But I want it to be dynamic based on the logged in user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **[`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)** factory instead of using `$http`. As stated in the documentation `$resource` is:

> A factory which creates a resource object that lets you interact with
>   RESTful server-side data sources.

To do what you want, you can simply declare it like this:

```
factory('User', function($resource) {
    var UserResource = $resource('/api/users/:id');
    return UserResource;
});
```

Usage:

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, User) {

   // Sends GET /api/users/1
   User.get({id: '1'}).$promise.then(function(user) {
     // expects a single user data object
     console.log(user);
   });

   // Sends GET /api/users
   User.query().$promise.then(function(users) {
     // expects an array of user data objects
     console.log(users);
   });
});
```

Comment: I know :P was waiting for the time limit.  Thanks again